# Add Push Notification to flutter iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add iOS Push Notification (Firebase Cloud Messaging) in XCODE But no response
I tried to clone the project to another MacBook but still getting the same results
when I create new project I can add it normally but I don't know what is wrong with this project and I tried aloso

```
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
pod cache clean --all
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod repo update
pod install
```

```html
<img src="https://s8.gifyu.com/images/FormatFactory-Screen-Record20220519_134011-min.gif" alt="FormatFactory Screen Record20220519 134011 min" width="724" height="370" data-is360="0" data-load="full" class="" style="width: 724px; height: 370px;">
```

I tried to add this key to info.plist aps-environmentaps but I didn't find it
if any one have any I idea about this problem and how to solve it please help.

Comment: have you set the apn or keys from developer apple account?

Comment: No, Where should I add it ?

Comment: Notification using firebase right?

Comment: First you need some developers account in apple because the apn can be download after you create profile, certificates, identifiers and other things notification in ios is quite have lot to do but surely it's quite good since they are quite safe on things for giving apn token

Comment: yes firebase notifications. I have added apple key to firebase before
should I add any configuration to xcode?